# TypeError: object Message can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, telegram-bot, async-await

При вводе /start сообщение выводится , но сразу за ним выскакивает ошибка
TypeError: object Message can't be used in 'await' expression
Ребят, я только начинаю изучать АСИНХРОННОСТЬ. И я вожусь с этой ошибкой уже более часа , поэтому очень надеюсь на помощь!!!

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def menu(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "БОТ ЕЩЁ В РАЗРАБОТКЕ") # ошибка здесь
```

Comment: https://nabtron.com/typeerror-object-dict-cant-be-used-in-await-expression/

Comment: Что у вас за библоиотека

Comment: @oleksandrigo связанная с async и await никакой(

Answer (score 0):

Фактически, можно сделать так:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def menu(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "БОТ ЕЩЁ В РАЗРАБОТКЕ")
```

Бот может работать без асинхронных функций, а в вашем случае, он ругается на await.

Comment: да это работает, но тогда почему люди пишут ботов через асинхронность? И при этом у них нет никакой ошибки казалось в таком простом коде?

Comment: Поэтому что они пишут их на асинхронных библиотеках